# Verify that npm version has increased in CI build

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, microservices

In the Continuous Integration (CI) pipeline, as part of the checks, I would like to verify that the version of the package has increased.

**Any ideas on what could be the best approach?**

Currently the pipeline runs

- `npm run lint` for linting.
- `npm run test` for unit test coverage.
- `npm run build` to generate the production build.

If any of them fail the branch won't be able to merge. Currently, we have to remember to increase the package version but a lot of times people forget. As we have use them inside a microservices infrastructure we really need this to upgrade the version. It would be great to include a check for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call for the package latest version on NPM registery by code and in that stage check for versions.following code get package version from registery:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const ver = spawn("npm", ["view", "<packagename>", "version"]);

ver.stdout.on("data", data =>{
    // you would have the latest version of the package from npm
    // check packages here
});

ver.stderr.on("data", err => console.error(err));

ver.on("exit", code => {
    if(code ===0 ){
        // process finished succesfully and do whatever you want
    }
});
```